# Thymeleaf Dynamic List using Jqueryui Sortable Collection and Spring

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, spring-mvc, servlets, thymeleaf

I am looking to utizlie Thymeleaf and JQuery UI Sortable Collections. The UI example I am looking to follow exists here. http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

In my Controller I have two lists that are passed to the model, one that is initially empty and another that has items. I am looking to drag columns from the list with items and sort them into the empty list. I would then like to submit this as a form back to the application. Currently though I can't determine a good way to dynamically add items to the list and submit them back to the application with updated values.

Currently I am using the short piece of javascript below to assign a integer list of ids to an input value. Is there a better method for doing this in Thymeleaf dynamically? Or possibly with another framework inside the same page?

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#list1, #list2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"  ,
      update: function () { save_new_order() }
    }).disableSelection();
  });

  function save_new_order() {
        var a = [];
        $('#list1').children().each(function (i) {
            a.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        var s = a.join(',');
        var div = document.getElementById('inputIds');
        div.value = s;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you using `List<Integer>` try using `#list.sort()`

```
<th:each="l, iter : ${#list.sort(LISTNAME)}">
```

Refer this : [Using #list.sort()](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/lists-sort-with-java-util-List-provided-by-Spring4-td4027684.html)

Comment: Alfi, my original post may not have been clear enough, I have updated it. I'm not looking to sort the items in the list but transfer the items between lists and submit these back to the application.